# How to solve warning for variable initialization C++

Tags: c++, variables, gcc-warning

I got the following warning when compiling a C++ file :

```
variables.cpp:10:8: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
   int c{2} ;
```

This is the file :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std ;

int main()
{
  int a = 0 ;
  int b(1) ;
  int c{2} ;

  string myString = "I am a string !" ;

  cout << a+b+c << endl ;
  cout << myString << endl ;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS ;
}
```

And this is the command line :

```
g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -Wextra -Winit-self -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual -Wuninitialized -Wmissing-declarations -Winit-self -ansi -pedantic variables.cpp -o variables
```

I am using g++ 7.4.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.1
I do not want to ignore the warning but to solve it,
Thank you

PS : I tried to change -std=c++0x to -std=c++11 but it did not change anything

Comment: What version of gcc are you using?

Comment: *"PS : I tried to change -std=c++0x to =std=c++11"* -- that should be a `-` in front of the `std` in `=std=c++11`

Comment: Use `-std=c++11` when compiling

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Remove `-ansi` in your command, which is equivalent to `-std=c++98` and would overwrite your previous flag `-std=c++11`. According to [C-Dialect-Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options),

   > In C mode, this is equivalent to -std=c90. In C++ mode, it is equivalent to -std=c++98.
2. Replace `-std=c++0x` with `-std=c++11`.

---

Note that if your compiler supports it, it is recommended to use the lastest c++ standard which is `-std=c++17`. Using newer c++ standard usually makes your code shorter, more readable and more performant.

Comment: Bit more clarification: If options conflict, then the rightmost option applies.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning somewhere in this question/answer that c++17 is the latest official standards release in gcc (later ones are drafts), so unless they have a specific reason to be on c++11 (or anything earlier), the recommended flag is `-std=c++17`.  See here for more info: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx17

Comment: @KevinAnderson Not everyone has the latest gcc installed. For examples, many are still using ubuntu 16.04, where the "default" gcc does not support `-std=c++17`.

Comment: @KevinAnderson I followed your advice because I am on Ubuntu 18.04 so I can use the latest relase

Comment: @ZhengQu you are right of course about if they don't have 17 they can't use it (until recently I was also limited to 11 due to "reasons"), but I appreciate you editing your answer to go with the latest as the "Default" option.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problem in compilation command line:

The first one is the `-ansi` in compilation command that implicitly set the standard to the c++98. In you case the `-ansi` option generate conflict with `-std=c++11`.

The second one is the `-std=c++0x`, you have to replace it with `-std=c++11`.